# Changing DateFormat from EU to US entityFramework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, datetime

Hello I have little problem with `DateTime` formats in `SQL server`.
I have an app which connects with `SQL Server 2012`. 
I need to use EU Dateformat in App. SQL server holds DateTime in EU Format
proof:

[image]

But when I allow users to enter date in EU format `EntityFramework` throws `Model not valid`
I suppose that C# default DateTimeformat is US
how to modify this code to let user enter EU format date and pass it to DB without any problems:
My model:

```
namespace magazyn.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class DeviceInstance
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int DeviceId { get; set; }
        public string SerialNo { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }

        public virtual Device Device { get; set; }
        public virtual DeviceUsage DeviceUsage { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have a DateTime field on the view and use the value from this field in code you have normaly no problem.
I work usually with mysql and there I need to convert from a datetime var to a string in the format 'yyyy-MM-dd'
Maybe that helps you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> SQL server holds DateTime in EU Format

No, it doesn't. (At least, not if it's in an appropriate column type in the database.) It holds it in a more compact binary format - at least so I assume. That's an implementation detail though. Fundamentally, the point is that it's a date/time value. You should *always* talk to the database in terms of a `DateTime` value (or `DateTimeOffset` or whatever), not in terms of a string. That way, you won't get involved in conversion. What you see in your SQL Explorer (or whatever you're using to query it) is just *a string representation* of what's in the database. That isn't the same as the value that's in the database.

In the same way, you could ask the database to display a number as decimal or hex - that doesn't change the fundamental numeric value.

You need to perform an appropriate conversion of the user-entered data *in your application*, and again to display any data from the database to the user, but there should be no need to use a string representation beyond that "user boundary".

You should try to make the vast majority of your code work with a non-string-based representation. Convert input data to the "natural" representation as early as you possibly can, and convert output data to a culture-specific string representation as late as you possibly can.